# Judgment about obligatory de se reading

Tags: syntax, english, semantics

> (1) John himself said he hates himself.
>
> (2) John said he hates himself.

In sentence (1), does *he* obligatorily refer to *John*? Or it can refer to other people as well like in sentence (2).

In more detail, if in (1) *he* refers to *John* only, is it because the first *himself* in the sentence gives obligatory *de se* reading to the pronoun?

Comment: I am not sure if it is a grammatical sentence but I found it on google.

Comment: What is the semantic difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: To me, the extra _himself_ serves only to emphasise who the speaker is. It changes nothing about who ‘he’ is – it can be John or someone else in both cases.

Comment: 'he" can refer to another man or boy.

Comment: thanks for your clarification! @JanusBahsJacquet I understand that the adjunct doesn't change the reference.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"John himself" implies that it was less expected that John would do so, and in this usage is synonymous with the word "even", as in, "Even John did so."

*John is a motivational speaker who always encourages people to love themselves and will never declare that somebody authentically hates themselves; instead, he will always encourage them to realise that they do not actually hate themselves, deep inside. Still, people were skeptical even John could have this optimistic attitude when he met Gregor, an unusually self-loathing person. After their encounter, the participants in the seminar were enthused that, as expected, pretty much every person there had felt that Gregor truly did hate himself and would never budge in his views towards himself - even the speaker. John himself said that he hates himself.*

Comment: thanks very much @John Smith I am wondering if the appositive intensifier _himself_ triggers any presupposition. It is just my naive thought when you said that _"John himself" implies that it was less expected that John would do so._. Thanks for providing a case with context. It straightforwardly presents a good interpretation of the distinction between the two sentences.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know how this or that technical framework would analyse how *himself* alters the content of the sentence. I think both semantics and pragmatics might have something to say about it. Semantically, possibly conveying a "mood" (intensified, unexpected, stands out), or, implying that the default understanding would have been somebody else on his behalf - If John is a King whose servants bring gifts wherever he goes, it would be interesting if John not only brought a cake (in the sense that he arranged for it but technically his servants did the actual delivery) - but (cont.)

Comment: but John himself brought a cake. (It is unusual for a person of high status like John to carry physical objects). I do not know if that counts as a "presupposition" but if you want to decompose the sentence it could be something like: 1. There is a man called John. 2. There is a cake. 3. The cake is such that John brought it. 4. The cake is such that John performed the action of bringing (as opposed to being associated with the goal or result or something.) I am not sure about pragmatics but I wonder if anaphora could have some role, like the sentence would not make sense without a context

Comment: in which it had been established that by default it would not have been John himself who did something. I.e., "John himself went for a run" could sound odd if all you really meant to say was "John went for a run." I don't know too much about pragmatics though.

Comment: Sorry, as with so many of my answers on this site, the moment I write them I start to doubt them. This could use a lot more analysis. I can think of a couple readings so far, but I am not fully sure why they work the way they do. One might be topicalisation: Richard built a canoe. Peter built a swingset. John himself built a cabin. (= As for John, ...) A second specifically implies they *did it themself*: John himself fixed the flat tire (it really emphasises we would not expect John to get on his hands and knees and dirty), like, "Can you believe it? John actually got out the tools and fixed

Comment: it himself". I am not sure I have a theory unifying these uses except possibly what I originally said: it somehow "emphasises" how striking it is that *John* did something, but it is possible that it is heavily context-dependent why it is so striking. With this hypothesis, we could look for other possible moods conveyed, I'm not sure.

Comment: My current hypothesis is that it is a highly general-purpose "emphasizer" similar to how we use *italics* *just to make something stand out in some way but there are a range of tones or attitudes it could be used for which would be apparent  from the context* (profundity, secrecy, awfulness, wonder, or just trying to make your intended meaning extra clear). So far this is the best hypothesis I have.

Comment: thanks very much for your further comments! I agree with you that the emphasizer (I would call intensifier) stands out in the semantics and I think it triggers alternatives that _John_ is somehow more central with respect to alternatives as what you say.

Comment: As for the two sentences: _John himself went for a run._ and  _John went for a run himself. _ I have seen some people analyze it as an extraposition in the second sentence. It is moved from the position in (1) indicating it is just_John_ alone. John went for a run alone or by himself. The second sentence is more natural without context whereas the first one needs context to make sense.

Comment: I remember that the focus particle "only" or "even'' can trigger alternatives. For example. _Only John went for a run_. It indicates that no one else went for a run except John. For the sentence, _John himself went for a run_. It also triggers alternatives. What you have proposed is very insightful that is also consistent with my observation. Some scholars might also consider _himself_ as a floating quantifier. I am not very clear about it but I think it makes sense at some point.